# How to use specific users in Meteor using accounts-ui

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

So im new to meteor, and im trying to make an app that uses specific users that I want, and put them on a members list. I made the users, but when I tried to put them in like this, they weren't showing up in the members box

```
<div id="members" class="side-box">
<h3>Memebers</h3>
<div class="box-content">
  <div><a class="filter-user">{{username.bob}}</a></div>
  <div><a class="filter-user">{{username.joe}}</a></div>
  <div><a class="filter-user">{{username.bill}}</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there another way to use specific users?

Comment: Can you please show the publication of the users and the subscription to it?

Comment: im sorry, im really new to meteor, and I have no idea on how to get the publication or subscriptions. I just downloaded the accounts-ui and accounts-password, and created a bunch of accounts in them.

Comment: where and how is username defined? How did you "make" the users? What's the content of the users collection in mongo now?

Comment: so I just made it how any user would make it, as in I just clicked create an account, and created a couple mock people. I just implemented the accounts-Ui just the way it was without tweaking it or anything. they dont really have any content, so far as what i understand.